# Installing GPAW (Python DFT package) on a computing cluster

Tags: python, parallel-computing, computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I'm in the middle of installing GPAW on a cluster but I'm running into problems building the "gpaw-python" interpreter, its job is to allow users to execute parallelised GPAW calculations. Following the Developer Installation guide [here](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/gpaw/devel/developer_installation.html#developer-installation), I've downloaded the most recent stable package and got it working fully on my local desktop, including the gpaw-python interpreter, and currently have the gpaw.tar file unzipped and ready to go on the cluster, which I am accessing through ssh.

The specific part where the problem occurs is building the C extensions, as seen at the start of the developer guide. I've ensured that I have mpicc installed as required and it links to the command line ok, albeit this is through a software module on the cluster which is available to all users (this version is gcc/4.6.3/openmpi/64/1.6.1). Note the caveat in the developer installation guide requiring mpicc in order to construct the gpaw-python interpreter.

When I run

> python setup.py build_ext 2>&1 | tee build_ext.log

Everything looks okay and the expected *location* of the "gpaw-python" executable is built in

> ```
>    $GPAW_HOME/build/lib.<platform>-<python_version>/
> ```

but doesn't anything, so I would guess the installation is missing mpicc somehow. When I tried installing GPAW locally there wasn't a problem doing this so maybe I'm missing some subtlety when working on the cluster?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! This sort of question is probably better asked on the GPAW mailing list. Also, in the sentence ending with "...but doesn't anything, so I would guess the installation is missing mpicc somehow", there seems to be a verb missing between "doesn't" and "anything".

Answer (score 1):

Problem can be fixed by adding this around line 395 in the config.py file, inside the build_interpreter function:

```
define_macros.append(('_GNU_SOURCE', '1'))
```

where the other define_macros.append commands reside.